# Applying lambda function to dataframe results in no output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, variance

I have a DataFrame that contains the percent change in a stock price for a years worth of data. I am trying to write a function that computes the annualized volatility of a stock. Here is my function:

```
def getVolatility(stock):
  data = stock.history(period="1y")
  data['PCT'] = data['Close'].astype(float).pct_change().apply(lambda x: np.log(1+x))

  data_pct = data['PCT']

  mean = "{:.15f}".format(data_pct.mean())
  #sqd = data_pct.apply(lambda x: (x-mean)**2)

  print(mean)
  #print(sqd)
```

The line that is commented out, `#sqd = data_pct.apply(lambda x: (x-mean)**2)` is meant to compute the numerator in the variance equation. However, when the line is uncommented the entire function fails to print. `data_pct` works in the line above the commented out one, so I am confused as to why `#sqd = data_pct.apply(lambda x: (x-mean)**2)` is the one not working.

When commented out, the mean is calculated and prints.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this function essentially causes the entire function to not do things that I know work such as print?

Comment: `mean` is a string.  You can't use a string in arithmetic.  Do `mean = data_pct.mean()`.  You can convert it to a string later.

Comment: Wow, sometimes after looking at code for awhile you begin to glance over the smaller details. Thank you for the fix @TimRoberts

Comment: @TimRoberts consider writing an answer as your comment solved OP's problem.